# commit/rollback em duas tabelas com PDO

Tags: php, pdo, commit, rollback

Antes de mais nada, o código abaixo funciona, não há qualquer erro (mas possivelmente pode ser melhorado). Tenho o seguinte método no PHP:

```
<?php
public function ajustarUnidadeServidor($ajusteExercicio){
    try {
        $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO tb_ajuste_exercicio ( siape_administrador,
                                                    siape_servidor,
                                                    id_unidade_anterior, 
                                                    id_nova_unidade) 
        VALUES (:siape_administrador,
                :siape_servidor,
                :id_unidade_anterior, 
                :id_nova_unidade);";

        $stmt = Conexao::instanciar()->prepare($sqlInsert);

        $stmt->bindValue(":siape_administrador", $ajusteExercicio);
        $stmt->bindValue(":siape_servidor", $ajusteExercicio);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_unidade_anterior", $ajusteExercicio);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_nova_unidade", $ajusteExercicio);

        $insert = $stmt->execute();

        $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE tb_servidor SET id_unidade_exercicio = :id_nova_unidade 
                    WHERE siape_servidor = :siape_servidor;";

        $stmt = Conexao::instanciar()->prepare($sqlUpdate);

        $stmt->bindValue(":id_nova_unidade", $idNovaUnidade);
        $stmt->bindValue(":siape_servidor", $siapeServidor);

        $update = $stmt->execute();


        return ($insert && $update);

    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        GeraLog::instanciar()->inserirLog("\nArquivo de origem: _ServidorCompletoDAO.php" . "\nCódigo do erro: " . $e-> getCode() . "\nMensagem: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

Minha dúvida é: como faço para dar `commit` e `rollback` neste código, considerando que pode ocorrer um erro no `$sqlUpdate` e preciso dar rollback em toda a transação? Eu vi que posso fazer `$stmt->beginTransaction();` no começo e `$stmt->commit();` ou `$stmt->rollBack();` em caso de sucesso/falha, mas o `rollback` vai funcionar para as duas tabelas relacionadas?

Comment: O `rollback()` vai anular/desfazer todas as instruções dentro daquele bloco(transação). O `commit()` vai colocar todas as alterações daquela transação em vigor. siape me parece familiar esse nome.

Comment: sim, essa informação eu sabia. Meu problema é: como colocar isso no meu código, só tenho os conceitos mas não um exemplo prático que se encaixe na minha situação. E @rray, SIAPE é um número que identifica servidores públicos.

Answer (score 2):

**Problema resolvido!**

Meu erro foi tentar fazer `stmt->commit()` ou `stmt->rollBack()`, onde na verdade era para eu ter feito isso na conexão. Atribuí a conexão a uma variável `$conn` e deu tudo certo. Meu método ficou assim:

```
public function ajustarUnidadeServidor($ajusteExercicio){
try {
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO tb_ajuste_exercicio ( siape_administrador,
                                                    siape_servidor,
                                                    id_unidade_anterior, 
                                                    id_nova_unidade) 
        VALUES (:siape_administrador,
                :siape_servidor,
                :id_unidade_anterior, 
                :id_nova_unidade);";

    $conn = Conexao::instanciar();
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
    $stmt->bindValue(":siape_administrador", $ajusteExercicio['siape_administrador']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":siape_servidor", $ajusteExercicio['siape_servidor']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id_unidade_anterior", $ajusteExercicio['id_unidade_anterior']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id_nova_unidade", $ajusteExercicio['id_nova_unidade']);
    $insert = $stmt->execute();


    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE tb_servidor SET id_unidade_exercicio = :id_nova_unidade 
                    WHERE siape_servidor = :siape_servidor;";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUpdate);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id_nova_unidade", $ajusteExercicio['id_nova_unidade']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":siape_servidor", $ajusteExercicio['siape_servidor']);
    $update = $stmt->execute();

    if($insert && $update){
        $conn->commit();
        return true;
    } else {
        $conn->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    GeraLog::instanciar()->inserirLog("\nArquivo de origem: _ServidorCompletoDAO.php" . "\nCódigo do erro: " . $e-> getCode() . "\nMensagem: " . $e->getMessage());
}
}
```